# What’s the best approach to compute distance between DOM Elements in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a tool to generate pdf file from data, and I need to build in two formats : 105mm * 148mm and 105mm * 210mm. So I got my entire document and now it's time for me to insert page breaks. I do it with a simple class:

```
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
```

Now I have to insert this class into my v-for loop. So a basic idea is to compute an interval, like each the index is a multiple of 6, I insert one. But it's not the best way to do it, I want to insert a break when the content is above 90mm.

In order to do that, I wanted to compute the distance between 2 breaks and insert a new one if the distance is near 90mm. But, I can't find a way to access to my dynamic DOM elements...

So the question is simple: How to compute this distance? Or if there is a better way to achieve my goal, what can I improve?

Comment: is it possible to add some code.

Comment: @hardik-satasiya done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are adding a div/component in each `v-for` and you can add an unique id to each div. Now below methods can give you height of one div in `px`, and you will have some way to convert `px` to `mm`.

If you are using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/height/), you can do

```
$('#nthDiv').height();
```

If not, you can do following:

[inner height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight):

```
document.getElementById('#nthDiv').clientHeight;
```

[outer height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight):

```
document.getElementById('#nthDiv').offsetHeight;
```

if you have following code:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="{'page-break': isBreakNeeded(index)}" :id="index + 'thDiv'">
   ///Your code
</div>
```

You need to add following method:

```
isBreakNeeded (index) {       
   var height = 0
   do {
      index -= 1;
      height += document.getElementById('#' + index + 'thDiv').offsetHeight; 
      } while (index >= 0 || pageBreakAdded[index] == true)
      if(height > threshold){
         pageBreakAdded[index] = true
         return  true
      }
      else{
         return  false
      }
}
```

You need to add a following hash as well in the data attribute of your vue element, which will keep track of at what indexes you have added page break:

```
pageBreakAdded: {}
```

Comment: Good idea with a `v-if`condition, maybe it will be faster.

Comment: @GeorgeAbitbol DId you find this approach useful, do you see any concerns here?

Comment: @Saurabh, Seems you master vue.js. I need your help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843823/how-to-display-button-link-with-vue-js

Answer (score 2):

So, I tried this approach:

1. insert a `page-break` inside my loop template (`div v-for each data text element`)
2. select all the `page-break` after the rendering
3. compute using `getBoundingClientRect()`

   1. loop through the selection
   2. get the distance between the current break and the following one
   3. if it's outside an acceptable range, delete him from the DOM.

This method works but it's very ugly, it's very difficult to compute a good range, and it's super expensive! With a small dataset it's ok but with an entire book, it's too long...

And this is a first attempt to do it (with `Vue` templating)

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="page-footer">
        <div class="page-break"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="dynamic">
        <div v-for="(entry, index) in conv" class="row">
          <div v-if="entry.msgs[0].value === 'break'">
            <span class="date">{{entry.msgs[0].metadate}}</span>
          </div>

          <div v-else>
            <span class="author">{{ entry.user }}</span>
            <span class="hour">{{ entry.msgs[0].metahour }}</span>
            <div class="phrases">
              <span v-for="msg in entry.msgs">
                {{ msg.value }}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="page-footer" :data-base="index">
            <span class="page-number" :data-base="index">{{ pageNumberFor(index) }}</span>
            <div class="page-break"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page-footer" data-base="end">
        <span class="page-number" data-base="end">{{ pageNumberFor('end') }}</span>
        <div class="page-break"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import und from 'underscore'

export default {
  name: "Data",

  data () {
    return {
      conv: null,
      cleaned: false,
      pageNumbers: {}
    }
  },

  computed: {
    mmScale: () => 0.264583333,
    heightBreak: () => 210
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$http.get('static/data_sorted_backup.json').then(
    // this.$http.get('static/data_sorted.json').then(
      (response) => {
        this.conv = this.groupBy(response.data)
      },
      (response) => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    )


  },

  updated () {
    console.log('updated');
    if(!this.cleaned) this.cleanPageBreak()
  },

  methods: {
    groupBy (json) {
      let result = []
      result.push(json[0])

      let punc = new RegExp(/[\?\.\!\;\(\)]?$/, 'ig')

      for (var i = 1; i < json.length; i++) {
        let val = json[i].msgs[0].value
        val = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
        if( punc.test(val) === false ) val += '.'
        json[i].msgs[0].value = val

        let len = result[result.length -1].msgs.length
        // if it's not the same day

        let origin = result[result.length -1].msgs[len - 1].metadate
        let new_entry = json[i].msgs[0].metadate
        // console.log(i, origin, new_entry);
        if( origin !== new_entry ){
          result.push({
            msgs: [{
              value:"break",
              metadate: json[i].msgs[0].metadate
            }]
          })
          i--
          continue;
        }

        // if the previous author is the same
        if(result[result.length -1].user === json[i].user){
          result[result.length -1].msgs.push({
            value: json[i].msgs[0].value,
            metadate: json[i].msgs[0].metadate,
            metahour: json[i].msgs[0].metahour
          })

        }else{
          result.push(json[i])
        }
      }

      return result
    },

    cleanPageBreak () {
      console.log('cleanPageBreak');
      let breaks = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.page-footer')
      let distance
      let enough
      let previousTop = breaks[0].getBoundingClientRect().top

      let seuil = this.heightBreak * 0.85

      console.log(breaks.length, seuil);

      for (let i = 1; i < breaks.length; ++i) {
        console.log(i);
        distance = (breaks[i].getBoundingClientRect().top - previousTop) * this.mmScale

        enough = distance < this.heightBreak && distance >= seuil


        if (enough) {
          previousTop = breaks[i].getBoundingClientRect().top
        } else if(i != breaks.length -1) {
          breaks[i].remove()
        }
      }
      this.cleaned = true
      this.mapNumbers()
    },

    mapNumbers () {
      console.log('mapNumbers');
      let numbers = Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll('.page-number'))

      numbers.map( (elem, index) => {
        this.pageNumbers[elem.dataset.base] = {}
        this.pageNumbers[elem.dataset.base].index = index + 1
      })
    },

    pageNumberFor (index) {
      if(this.pageNumbers[index]) return this.pageNumbers[index].index
      return 0
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Abhaya+Libre');


.page-footer{
  position: relative;
  margin: 12mm 0;
  // border: 1px dotted black;

  .page-break   {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }

  .page-number {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: -28mm;
  }
}

.content {
  padding: 0 16mm 0 10mm;
  font-family: 'Abhaya Libre', serif;

  .pages{
    position: relative;
  }
}
.row {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;

  span{
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  span:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .date, .hour {
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  }
  .date {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10mm;
    padding-bottom: 2mm;
  }
  .author{
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hour {
    margin-bottom: 3mm;
    margin-top: -2px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  .phrases{
    text-indent:5mm;
  }
}

.row + .row {
  margin-top: 5mm;
}
</style>
```